# Highlighting(animate) a piechart slice from an HTML element (mouseover)

Tags: jquery, html, highcharts

I have a series of HTML table cells with data - an example of which is:

```
<tr id="rrow1">
  <td>
    <a href="/electricity" class="category">Electricity</a>
  </td>
  <td>
    901.471
  </td>
</tr>

<tr id="rrow2">...
<tr id="rrow3">...
etc
```

In this case, each `<tr>` (or hypathetically for the wider community a `div`/`span`/`tr`/`td`) is assigned a sequential id based on `$rrow++;` in a while loop (in PHP).

I also have a [Piechart](http://jsfiddle.net/xN3DQ/5/) using the [highcharts library](http://highcharts.com), where i'd like to highlight the slice (`sliced: true`) based upon onmouseover of particular `div`/`span`/`tr`/`td` element - in this case `#rrow1` as above, but multiple/iterative elements as required and (`sliced: false`) onmouseout...

As a simple example, I've tried accessing various derivatives of the following, but failed:

```
$('#rrow1').mouseover(function() {
    chart.series[0].graph.attr('sliced', true);
});

$('#rrow1').mouseout(function() {
    chart.series[0].graph.attr('sliced', false);
});
```

The nearest I've found is this but bastardised at most and without success:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
        mouseOver: function() {
          if( $('#rrow1').mouseover )
            series.x = sliced: true;
        },
        mouseOut: function() {
          if( $('#rrow1').mouseout )
            series.x = sliced: false;
        }
      }
    }
```

These are far from approaching correct and despite searching I can't find a valid/helpful example to work from or draw direction.

You can view the pie chart in question on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xN3DQ/5/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Animate on mouseover**

There's a function that slice the peace of pie, you can call it on each point event.

```
plotOptions: {
    series; {
        point: {
            events: {
                mouseOver: function() {
                    this.slice();
                },
                mouseOut: function() {
                    this.slice();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Updated [your chart](http://jsfiddle.net/xN3DQ/4/).

**Animate from a external element**

First of all you have to identify which slice you have to animate. Iou can do it using an `id` for each `slice`, and **store the same id on the respective html element**.
Then you can use `chart.get(id);` to get the slice, and call `slice` function.

Like this:
**My series**

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Share',
    data: [{
        name: 'Electricity',
        id: 'eletricity-slice'
    }, {
        name: 'Heating Oil',
        id: 'oil-slice'
    }, {
        name: 'Gas',
        id: 'gas-slice'
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        id: 'other-slice'
    }]
}]
```

**My HTML**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr data-slice="eletricity-slice"><td>Electricity</td></tr>
    <tr data-slice="oil-slice"><td>Heating Oil</td></tr>
    <tr data-slice="gas-slice"><td>Gas</td></tr>
    <tr data-slice="other-slice"><td>Other</td></tr>
</table>
```

This way I know which element slices which point. Then I only have to **bind the events**.

```
$('table').on('mouseover mouseout', 'tr', function() {
    var sliceId = $(this).data('slice'); // get data attr which contais the id
    animateSlice(chart.get(sliceId));    // pass slice point as parameter
});
```

I create the function `animateSlice` to animate which slice I want, so you can call it from your chart events too, like:

```
mouseOver: function() {
    animateSlice(this);
},
mouseOut: function() {
    animateSlice(this);
}
```

And here's `animateSlice` function:

```
function animateSlice(point) {
    point.slice();
}
```

So, here is [**the result**](http://jsfiddle.net/cH7NV/).

Comment: This is close, but how do I slice/unslice from an external `<tr>` or other HTML element using mouseover/mouseout? See: [http://jsfiddle.net/xN3DQ/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/xN3DQ/5/)

Comment: That's perfect and well authored. Thank you!